# Does MS CRM 2011 require Active Directory

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We're looking to implement an IFD of CRM 2011 for a client and I am curious about whether Active Directory is a prerequisite.  We'd like to set up a standalone environment using ASP.Net membership provider.

Is this possible?

Thank you,

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working Active Directory is a **must** requirement for a Dynamics CRM deployment. See the planning section of the Implementation Guide

- [Active Directory and network requirements for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699832.aspx)
- [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2011 software requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699671.aspx)